# Ansible error handling for status code using failed_when

Tags: error-handling, ansible

I am trying to error handle in ansible for http status code. My use case is to check for status code 400(fail code) and it needs to pass for 2 known error conditions.
Like if content has particular search strings in 400 response.
Sample task:

```yaml
-name: create repo
uri:
    url:
    method: POST
    body_format:json
    .
    .
    status_code: 
        - 201 
        - 400
    register: value
    changed_when: value.status == 201
    failed_when: value.status == 400 and
                 value.content|default() is not search ("found duplicate value")
```

Above is working but
Expecting another search string with or condition to the same and 400 like.

```yaml
-name: create repo
 uri:
    url:
    method: POST
    body_format:json
    .
    .
    status_code: 
        - 201 
        - 400
    register: value
    changed_when: value.status == 201
    failed_when: value.status == 400 and
                 ( value.content|default() is not search ("found 1st duplicate value") or value.content|default() is not search ("found 2nd duplicate value") )
```

How to handle either condition 2 or's with the 'and'..

Answer (score 1):

i think you have parenthesis problem and you have to add simple quote:
try:

```
failed_when: (value.status == 400) and
             '(value.content|default() is not search ("found 1st duplicate value") or value.content|default() is not search ("found 2nd duplicate value"))'
```

Comment: Thanks Frenchy..tried the parenthesis like you said, But it didnt help me..meanwhile it works if i try with a single search string condition

Comment: i have added simple quote, it seems is search or is not search uses simple quote